# Getting Error with "pip install pyrebase"

Tags: pyrebase

```
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
command: 'c:\users\sasa_\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\python.exe' -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\sasa_\\AppData\\Local\
\Temp\\pip-install-dfyu35fv\\jws\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\sasa_\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-dfyu35fv\\jws\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'
"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' egg_info --egg-base 'C:\Users\sasa_\AppData
\Local\Temp\pip-install-dfyu35fv\jws\pip-egg-info'
         cwd: C:\Users\sasa_\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-dfyu35fv\jws\
    Complete output (7 lines):
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "C:\Users\sasa_\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-dfyu35fv\jws\setup.py", line 17, in <module>
        long_description=read('README.md'),
      File "C:\Users\sasa_\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-dfyu35fv\jws\setup.py", line 5, in read
        return open(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), fname)).read()
    UnicodeDecodeError: 'cp932' codec can't decode byte 0x93 in position 502: illegal multibyte sequence
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for full command output.
```

Tried with 
pip install --upgrade setuptools
pip install pycryptodome
pip install shapely==1.4.1
Still cant

Comment: Are you able to install any other packages with pip ?

Comment: yes i'm able to install other packages with no error beside this pyrebase